# Counting the Number of Reps From a Rep Height

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to calculate the number of reps from a rep height.

Example #1

Input: n = 2

Output: Result = 6

Because 1+2+2+1 = 6

--

Example #2

Input: n = 3

Output: Result = 12

Because 1+2+3+3+2+1 = 12

What formula could I use to get from input to output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My way before is unnecessarily long. When you add $(1 + 2 + \dots + n) + (n + (n-1) + \dots + 1)$, line up the pairs $(n, 1)$, $(2, n-1)$, $(3, n-2)$, and you'll notice that they all sum to $n+1$. Since you have $n$ pairs, the sum is $n(n+1)$.

Comment: Now I just have to figure out how to read this. :)
Thank you Taisuke.

Answer (score 1):

Let the 'output' be $S_n$. Then

$$S_n=1+2+...+n+n+(n-1)+...+1$$
$$=2(1+2+...+n)$$
(formula for [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number))
$$=2\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)$$
$$=n(n+1)$$